# restart hot corners

Tags: snow-leopard, spaces, expose

On Snow Leopard (latest version, but it's been happening for a while), I have the top right corner set to show Spaces, and the bottom right to show the Desktop. Occasionally, often enough to be annoying, and without any reason I can discern, these hot corners stop working. I have tried:

- changing the action of the hot corners, mouse in (nothing happens), then change back
- turning off Spaces and turning it back on
- toggling the Spaces icon in the menu bar (worth a shot, right?)
- `killall Finder`
- `killall Dock`
- `killall SystemUIServer`

None of these work. If I close the MacBook to suspend it, then bring it back up, that fixes the problem, but is less than ideal if I have, e.g. a big download going.

Is there a way to quickly (i.e. not log out/log in, not restart) fix the hot corners? Is there some special program I don't recognize in the System Monitor that will restart the hot corners if killed? Is there something that suspend recycles that I can recycle without suspending?

Comment: This could very well be related to http://apple.stackexchange.com/q/33950/10410, but that question doesn't have answers either, and I'm on Snow Leopard, not Lion. I therefore figured it was probably worth making a potential duplicate question.

Comment: Duh, I meant to try sleeping/closing laptop and waking back up. I'll see how that works too, next time it happens.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It happened again, and I tried simply closing the MacBook, waiting a couple of seconds, and reopening. Maybe it was a fluke, but it worked. I'll wait and see if it fixes the problem a second time to make sure that it really did something.

This answer is less than ideal, e.g., if I'm in the middle of a big download, so I'd like to wait and see if this answer can help towards a better solution. What does suspend trigger that I could do without suspending?

Answer (score 5):

Have you tried restarting SystemUIServer? (`killall SystemUIServer`) When something like his is happening and restarting the Dock doesn't help, SystemUIServer is the next one to try.

Comment: +1 This is one of the processes that frequently causes problems and can be killed harmlessly.

Comment: I'd seen the process in System Monitor, but didn't know if killing it would do anything harmful (to my desktop session). If it's harmless, I'll give your answer a shot when it next happens.

Comment: Happened again; didn't work. Bummer.

Answer (score 0):

Can you check in Mission Control if Hot corners are undefined? My Keynote crashed, and a consequence of this was, that the Hot corners have all been undefined in Mission Control.