# Mavericks Hot Corners does not work

Tags: macos

I have set up a hot corner for my screensaver on system preferences but it does not activate when i move my cursor to the appropriate corner of the screen.

Comment: Try `killall -HUP SystemUIServer Dock`

Comment: possible duplicate of [Hot Corners for Mission Control stop working](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/33950/hot-corners-for-mission-control-stop-working)

Comment: Has it worked before (e.g. Mountain Lion, Lion)?

Answer (score 2):

Usually this is a temporary glitch that a restart fixes. If you have this failing after that - you can test a new user account.

If that works, then your preference file needs to be cleared. See this post for details: [Hot Corners for Mission Control stop working](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/33950/hot-corners-for-mission-control-stop-working)